# javascript - Uncaught ReferenceError for a defined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Relevant Code:

```
// Flag For Showing/Hiding Start Campaign Button During Alarm
var blnCampaignStatusIsgood = false;

do {
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/getCampaigns.php,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        aysnc: false,
        success: function (res) {
            console.log("Loaded campaign info ...includes/getCampaigns.php");

            // Flag To Stop Ajax Calls
            blnCampaignStatusIsgood = true;
        },
        error: function (res) {
            console.log("Error checking for campaign info: " + res);
        }
    });
} while ( blnCampaignStatusIsGood == false );
```

When ran, I receive the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: blnCampaignStatusIsGood is not defined

On the line with the while condition.

I've tried various declarations of the variable name (with and without "var"), making it global at top of script, as well as changing the ajax request to a sync request.

Why is it saying it's undefined when I clearly define it just prior to the do/while loop?

Comment: this is going to spin really fast.... way too many requests.

Comment: looks like you have `good` cased 2 different ways

Comment: You define `blnCampaignStatusIsgood `, then reference `blnCampaignStatusIsGood`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is on the last line,  `blnCampaignStatusIsgood` no capital G

```
} while ( blnCampaignStatusIsGood == false );
```

Comment: holy crap if that's it! no sleep, no rockstar this morning, and a headache! might make my night. will report back!

Comment: One thing i would suggest as it picks up these things easier, is move all your JavaScript code into Typescript. You get extra functions, it compiles down to JavaScript, easy to pick up and it tells you about errors as your writing the code.